# Get the url of the background-image from an div elment with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element in a website that looks like this:

```
<div id="item" style="background-image: url('url to the image')"></div>
```

Now I need a javascript which extracts only the url of this background-image and replaces it with an url stored in a var.

How is this possible in a "neat" way :) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select the div by its `id` and use `setAttribute` to set the `style` attribute to a string containing the new url stored in `yourVar` like this:

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var newStyle = 'background-image: url(' + yourVar + ');';
item.setAttribute('style', newStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#item').css('background-image', 'url(' + var + ')');
```

Comment: The OP didn't say they were using jQuery. Bit much to expect them to include the whole library just for that...

Comment: @LeeTaylor I wouldn't say that's too much to expect. jQuery is quite common along with other similar libraries, but it should be disclosed that this requires jQuery.